# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: android, json

Hi I get this error message whenever I try to connect to my sql database:

`JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Getting the data from the database works fine, but when i try to get the data of he user who is logged in i get the above error.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    listView  = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    WebView ourBrow = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);

    accessWebService();

    return rootView;
}


// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListDrwaer();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = json.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("username");
           String adr = jsonChildNode.optString("adres");
           // String number = jsonChildNode.optString("password");
            String outPut = name + "-" + id + "-" + adr;
            userList.add(create_user("id","username", outPut));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), userList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "id"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> create_user(String name,String id, String adr) {
    HashMap<String, String> userNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userNo.put(name, adr);
    return userNo;
}

}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.app.MoviesFragment.ListDrwaer(MoviesFragment.java:110)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.app.MoviesFragment$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MoviesFragment.java:95)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.app.MoviesFragment$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MoviesFragment.java:55)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-25 10:26:42.690    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-25 10:26:42.700    5233-5233/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does the JSON data look like?

Comment: please show your json format

Comment: {"users":[{"id":"1","username":"ertas","adres":"street 62"}]}

Comment: is this failing before the `for` loop in `ListDrwaer()` or in it?

Comment: When I open the fragment I get the error immediately, but the app doesn`t crash I just get an empty page.When I just select * from users I don`t get an error , but when I`m trying to retrieve those data through a session i get this error

Comment: Your code swallow all exceptions because you use Toasts to show errors. Can you add some logs to print the exception stacktraces. Then  you can find the place that exception thrown.

Comment: I have added the logcat above

Answer (score 1):

```
String id = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
```

I think this code throws exception `typeMismatch`.

Try this:

```
int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
String usrNm = jsonChildNode.getString("username");
String adres = jsonChildNode.getString("adres");
```

Comment: It still doesn work. Iget the error Json object [] cannotbe converted. That means i doesnt even show the logged in data